# Sitecore Redirect module Regex Pattern Matching

Tags: redirect, sitecore, sitecore7

Using the 301 Redirect Module for Sitecore 7, I'm having a problem establishing the proper Requested Expression and Source values to use in the Sitecore Redirect Module.  I have an example url that is typically getting request that I want redirected to the home page of the site.

The example url requests all contain excite.com at the end of the URL:

```
https://www.example.com/products/foods/apples/excite.com
https://www.example.com/products/foods/oranges/excite.com
https://www.example.com/products/foods/pears/excite.com
```

I would like these requests that contain excite.com at the end to be redirected to the home page (https://www.example.com) but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: Which redirect module are you using? There are several on the marketplace and they all work slightly differently.

Comment: I'm using the 301 Redirect Module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the [301 Redirect Module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/3/301_Redirect_module.aspx?sc_lang=en) but have used similar modules. There are 2 issues that need resolving.

You need to create a redirect using the Pattern Match Redirect. The regex you need is "match any request that ends with `/excite.com`"

`.*(/excite.com)$`

The other issue is that Sitecore is seeing the `.com` part of the url as an extension and then filtering the request. You need to add `com` to the list of Allowed extensions.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, com</param>
        </processor>
      </preprocessRequest>      
    </pipelines>    
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

All that said, if you are using the IIS Rewrite module then you could just add a rule in there which will get resolved and redirect before you even hit the Sitecore pipelines and therefore you do not need to worry about the allowed extensions filter.

```
<rules>  
  <rule name="Redirect excite.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*(/excite.com)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

Change the regex to `(excite.com)$|.*(/excite.com)$` if you also want it to match `http://ww.example.com/excite.com`

Comment: This worked perfect!  1) the pattern (though I needed to adjust it for 301 Redirect Module as ^https://www.example.com/products/foods/(.+)/(.+)/(.+).com$)  2) Adding com as the allowed extension.