# Unable to pass static file through ASP.NET pipeline

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, http-status-code-404, iis-8

I have a ASP.NET web application (Sitecore), and I'm supposed to handle routes that end in .html via ASP.NET. Normally, as I've read, simply adding `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true"` in `/Configuration/system.WebServer/modules` in web.config should suffice.

However, I'm not seeing this behaviour.

Trying "test.html" gives me the default IIS 404 page, and the code that's supposed to run, doesn't.

The app pool is already in integrated mode and the property `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration` is already set to `true`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you handling your routing? Are you patching into the Sitecore pipelines? Could you post up some sample code. It could be due to `html` not being an [Allowed Extension in config](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39471240/661447).

Comment: The "Allowed extensions in config" got me searching in the output of showconfig.aspx and there I found the relevant processor in PreProcessRequest pipeline. I added html to the list of allowed and it worked. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your routes have been registered using Sitecore pipelines then you will need to include `html` in the list of `Allowed extensions`. Patch the config like below to include whatever extensions you require to be processed:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <preprocessRequest>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, html</param>
        </processor>
      </preprocessRequest>      
    </pipelines>    
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```